# Can I get the index of an item in a Mongoid::Criteria without calling entries first?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

in my case:

```
portfolio_items.published.sorted.entries.index { |x| x.id == item.id }
```

Is there a way not to have to call "entries", but instead to get this value from mongo(id) directly?

Comment: please provide more info! What models are in there? is `published` a scope?

Comment: Yes, both 'published' and 'sorted' are scopes on a model PortfolioItem. But the question should be valid for Criteria in general. Assume a query on entities Socks.where(color: 'red') - on which position lies the first entity with size > 42? Can I ask this without materializing the whole result set?